# Text goes out of container when ctrl-scrolling

Tags: html, css

I have a header on my website, with a list in it. The list is aligned properly on 100% size, but when I ctrl-scroll to expand, the text in the list goes out of the header area.

**HTML**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.header {
  background-color: #606060;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 125%;
  height: 4.5%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0px;
}
#headerLinks {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #aaaaaa;
}
#headerLinks li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#headerLinks a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#headerLinks a:hover {
  color: #cccccc;
}
.introContent {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  height: 40%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div id="headerLinks">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the list text to remain inside the header at all times.

*EDIT:* If I remove the height, since there is a position:fixed; the other containers will get overlapped by the header on zooming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.header {
  background-color: #606060;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  height: 2.5em;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0px;
}
#headerLinks {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #aaaaaa;
}
#headerLinks li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#headerLinks a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#headerLinks a:hover {
  color: #cccccc;
}
.introContent {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  height: 40%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div id="headerLinks">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to be able to scale everything relatively when you zoom you should use `em` units instead of percentages.

Answer (score 2):

In your `.header` class, remove the `height` attribute - the browser will set the height of that `div` based on the content inside it (in this case, your menu items).

Comment: If I remove the height, since there is a position:fixed; the other containers will get overlapped by the header on zooming...

Comment: That's the expected behavior for `position:fixed`, since it removes items from the page flow.  You might want to review [CSS Positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)